# Cassandra static session?

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

Can `Cluster`, `ISession` and `IMapper` instances be static in a web app, or we need separate ones for each user? I.e. is it OK to have all of these instantiated (**as static**) at application startup and then use them for all users? In the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.3/features/components/mapper/) it says that only one instance of ISession should be used per keyspace. I'm using only one keyspace, so is this OK, or would this be problematic? I'm using [DataStax C# Driver](https://datastax.github.io/csharp-driver/features/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you just need one instance of `ISession` for the application, i.e. singleton pattern.

However, if significant load is expected make sure you protect the creation of it from multiple attempts by whatever hosting environment you're using so that while a session is being established additional attempts are failed.

Comment: Can IMapper be made static aswell? I'm asking because it' slow to reinitialize it, because you also have to respecify the mapping configurations.

Comment: My entities are simple enough to not bother with mappers so I don't use them. The docs seem to be clear about how one should use it: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.3/features/components/mapper/

Comment: I'll take that as a yes :).